# Eliminate online sale and add WhatsApp Direct | PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop

I am new to Prestashop and I am using it to create a business website.

Basically I am using Prestashop to show only the products and not make any online sales.

Because of this, I don't need visitors to log in, create accounts, bookmark, or add to cart. (Picture 1)

[image: Picture 1]

I just need you to take them to WhatsApp instead of buying, consulting specifically for that product. (Picture 2)

[image: Picture 2]

How can I remove the Create Account, Login, "My Account" and "My Cart" functions?

Besides this, how could I change the PrestaShop logo in the administrator login and in the panel?

Note: I am from Argentina, and I am using Google translator haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can change logo from from Design > Themes & Logo tab

For making things like you explain
You can switch PrestaShop into catalog mode and keep display prices enabled

Shop Parameters > Product Settings

[image: enable catalog mode]